# Jarring triangle pattern when importing a unity FBX

Tags: import, normals, .fbx

[image: Screenshot demonstrating problem, with a jarring shadow difference between edges.]

This shape is just a flat rectangle with some "chipped off" pieces. I initially made it in unity and exported it as an .fbx & fed that into blender.

[image: Screenshot demonstrating the "embossed" looking trinagles are actually flat]

[image: In Edit Mode]

The "embossed" triangles are actually flat. I tried removing all materials, recalculating normals,
shade-smoothing a face, etc. to help.

I'm quite new to Blender, so I haven't figured out the right terms to search.

Comment: try other formats

Comment: I'm wondering if you have hidden faces inside the mesh? That can cause shading issues.

Comment: can you show an image in edit mode that shows the actual topology of the object?

Comment: @susu here's the view from one of the sides: https://imgur.com/a/nnThKww

Comment: @RonJensen ~~I think that's it! I selected one of the edges and deleted it, lo and behold there's just another one right underneath. :/~~ my bad, there aren't duplicate faces

Comment: @susu Sure thing, done.

Comment: You have "Faces" inside of the mesh. You need to delete those  >X > Delete Faces only. You can see them easier with "Select Faces" selected.